# How to call function withour rendering React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have that simple code, that checking user has been login:

```
function App() {
  const {isLoggedIn} = useAppSelector(state => state.userReducer)
  
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const token = useRef(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')|| '{}'))
  console.log(token)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userSlice.actions.setLoggedIn(token.current))
  }, [token.current])


  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Routes>
        <Route path ='/' element={<Layout/>}>
          <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path='registration' element={<Register/>}/>
          <Route path='login' element={<Login/>}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
```

}

I try use hook useEffect and i take token in localStorage as a dependencies, but that do not work anyway, only if start rendering, but me need call this function anytime, even if render never happen. How i can do this? Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Redux, so your

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')
```

shiuld be in your `initialState` when creating your redux store